# Get products with at least one category in Magento?

Tags: magento

I currently have products in categories and ones that aren't in any of the categories. This snippet of code would give me all the most recently added products in Magento:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter($preorderAttribute, array(
                    'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute($preorderAttribute)
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId($preorderValue)
                ))
                ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))
                ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                ->setPage(1, 12);
```

But it also gives products that are not in any categories. I want only products that are in one or more categories but NOT products that are not in any categories.

How can I do this with the above code?

Comment: did you find any solution? if you found any solution can u plz share it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me to show only particular two categories products.Hope it will work for u.

```
 $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                        array('finset' => '7'),
                        array('finset' => '8'))
                )
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
            foreach($_productCollection as $_testproduct){
                echo $_testproduct->getId()."<br/>";

            };
```